# booting up problems

Tags: boot

I have recently installed ubuntu budgie on my laptop but I am facing a problems of being unable to boot up. Every time it starts with disablement of SGX and it shows that "invalid record 4112 found". So on and so on. I don't know how to make it boot up. Can sb help me please?

Comment: Hello. It from the little bit you have said like a bad install. Did you verify the ISO that you downloaded before you made the live media to do the install? Also what is the version that you installed?

Comment: I guess it was versin 18 and sth. I downloaded it from official website.